# Yii2 разные пути при подключение стилей в OpenServer (Windows) и LAMP (Linux)

Tags: yii2, openserver, lamp

Приходится работать в разных ОС потому работаю через github, плюс еще тестовый сервер в сети. Не знаю как решить вопрос с синхронизацией.

LAMP:

```
class LoginAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web/web';
    public $css = [
        'css/font-awesome.min.css',
        'css/AdminLTE.min.css',
    ];
}
```

OpenServer:

```
class LoginAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        '/css/font-awesome.min.css',
        '/css/AdminLTE.min.css',
    ];
}
```

Естественно картинки в лэйаутах тоже надо править в зависимости от сервера.

LAMP

```
<img src="web/img/usiz_logo.png" alt="">
```

OenServer

```
<img src="/img/usiz_logo.png" alt="">
```

Comment: `.htaccess` может на LAMP нужно правильно настроить, чтобы корневая папка домена была `web`. В документации к yii есть настройки apache и настройки `.htaccess` тоже можно найти в нете

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, так и есть